# Stagger labels on an Influence plot in SAS?

Tags: graph, sas

I'm generating some plots (for a class) for a colorblind professor. The `JOURNAL2` style, in SAS, uses grey scale. However, the plots put all of the points right on top of each other. Is there an option to scatter them around the point or use call out lines so that they are easier to read?

Here's the code I'm using

```
ODS HTML STYLE = JOURNAL2;

PROC LOGISTIC DATA = fludata PLOTS(UNPACK ONLY LABEL) = (LEVERAGE DFBETAS DPC INFLUENCE PHAT);
    CLASS gender(PARAM    = ref REF = 'Female')
          newincome(PARAM = ref REF = '03 - High  ');
    MODEL flu(EVENT = 'Yes') =  gender newincome / CTABLE PPROB = .49 TO .5 BY .001;
    OUTPUT OUT = predict P = pred;
RUN;
```

Here's an example of an illegible plot:

[image: illegible]

Any thoughts about a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe. My guess is that you will need to generate the graph yourself from the output data. This might be a good question to ask SAS technical support.  http://support.sas.com

Comment: What version of SAS do you have?

Comment: @Joe SAS 9.3 with all available extra packages.

Answer (score 1):

Don's suggestion of contacting SAS Support is probably apropos, but in the meanwhile here's an example of rolling your own.

```
ODS HTML STYLE = journal;


data us_data;
set sashelp.us_data;
length density $8 seat_change $15;
if density_2010 < 50 then density="1 Low";
else if density_2010 < 400 then density="2 Med";
else density="3 High";
if seat_change_2010 > 0 then seat_change='Positive';
else seat_change="Nonpositive";
keep density seat_change region;
run;

PROC LOGISTIC DATA = us_data PLOTS(UNPACK ONLY LABEL) = (LEVERAGE DFBETAS DPC INFLUENCE PHAT);
    CLASS REGION(PARAM    = ref REF = 'Northeast')
          density(PARAM = ref REF = '3 High');
    MODEL seat_change(EVENT = 'Positive') =  REGION density / CTABLE PPROB = .49 TO .5 BY .001;
    OUTPUT OUT = predict P = pred difchisq=difchisq c=cidisp;
RUN;

proc sgplot data=predict;    
scatter x=pred y=difchisq /group=region groupdisplay=cluster datalabel;
run;
```

Obviously you'd have to run each one separately this way, although the programming isn't all that hard.

Comment: Huh... I don't have the sashelp.us_data dataset.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot - that's a 9.4 dataset.  Apparently it will eventually be available at http://support.sas.com/rnd/datavisualization/mapsonline/html/downloads.html but is not yet.